# mysql password on command line

Tags: centos, mysql

I can't seem to be this working.  I wanted to set a shell script for mysqldump backup some databases.

I have tried:

mysqldump -uroot -ppassword

mysqldump -u root -ppassword <-- online A's says this is supposed to work

mysqldump --user=root --password=password

I keep getting access denied for user root@localhost

if I do the old fashion mysqldump -uroot -p and enter pass all is good

centos 6.8
mysql 5.7
I did install mysql manually with:
http://www.tecmint.com/install-latest-mysql-on-rhel-centos-and-fedora/#

is there a mysql option that disables this?

Comment: and you are sure that you are entering the correct password?

Comment: You shouldn't provide the password as a parameter in a script, it will be visible for everybody who runs `ps` while it is running. See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861355/mysqldump-launched-by-cron-and-password-security) on how to provide the password in a secure way.

Comment: pass is correct, I know this isn't the best way but the reason I'm asking now is because it just doesn't work and I want to know why.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider mysql hides the password from ps

Answer (score 1):

This works for me
mysql -u bas -pmysecretpassword

if its for structrule use you can put your password in my.cnf file

like this :

```
[mysqldump]
user=bas
password=mysecretpassword
```

Comment: Sorry submited to soon

Comment: That's a possibly useful answer, but 'structrule' is not a word, and I can't figure out what you might have intended it to be.